# php curl загрузить файл, только если он был изменен после последней загрузки

Tags: php, curl

Вопрос такой: требуется регулярное обновление своего сайта данными с сайта-источника, где публикуются обновления через каждые 2 часа.

Данные я хочу получать с помощью curl. Выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```html
curl -O myurl.html "http://site.ru/dir"
```

Не могу понять только одного момента. Как мне сохранять данные ТОЛЬКО В ТОМ СЛУЧАЕ, ЕСЛИ ОНИ БЫЛИ ОБНОВЛЕНЫ с момента последнего сохранения.

Предполагается, что обновления на сайте источнике публикуются по расписанию каждые 2 часа. Но по факту обновление может появиться не в 10-00, а в 10-07, к примеру.

Читала про возможность задать параметры вроде таких:

```html
$ curl -z 29-Dec-18
```

Но не прописывать же мне дату и время вручную в скрипте после каждого обновления.

Подскажите, как решается такая задача.
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно добавлять заголовок `If-Modified-Since`, и если сайт в таком случае умеет отдавать 304 код, то скачаете только, то что изменилось.

Comment: Спасибо, Егор. А как-то можно настроить изменение времени на время последнего сохранения обновленных данных? Допустим, укажу я If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Dec 2018 16:30:00 GMT    Это время мне как менять после каждого успешного обновления?

Comment: `curl`, кажется, этого не умеет, но умеет `wget -N`.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, задача решена написанием другого скрипта, который авторизуется на сайте источнике и сравнивает дату/время последнего обновления из last-modified.

Т.е. первоначально дату/время последнего обновления записываем в файл lastUpdate.txt При каждой проверке получаем в переменную $up содержимое этого файла:
  $up=file_get_contents('lastUpdate.txt');

Далее при каждой проверке обновлений на сайте источнике создаем переменную $up2, в которую записываем данные о дате/времени обновления, полученные методом getlastmod();

Если $up != $up2, то запускаем exec() другой скрипт, получающий обновления curl-ом, и перезаписываем в файл lastUpdate.txt новое значение из $up2.

Как-то так.